# jQuery Append a <span> tag to a <h1> heading

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to make a tag in the tag  heading, for example:

```
<h1> example </h1>
```

I was cold and turn it into the following

```
<h1> <span> example </span> </h1>
```

Please help for the code manipulation.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use [wrapInner()](http://api.jquery.com/wrapInner/)

```
$('h1').wrapInner('<span />')
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/WWKLA/)

Comment: Excellent, thank you help, I have to apply and successfully. thanks a lot.